# background on top off background, surrounding content

Tags: html, css, background, border

So, im trying my hands on some html/css/js/jquery coding, and having been searching around for answers some days now. Im trying to make a clean website, and was basically wondering how to do this:

[image]

What my amazing paint skill are trying to explain is how to do the "border/background" around/behind the content. Not the blue white background but the light grey one. Been trying to use  and use css border/width/height etc. But cant seem to get anything to work properly. Like it should scale automatically with a menubar, as seen in the image. Appreciate any input.

Comment: are you referring to the shadow?
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

Comment: That just appears to be a main container for all the content that has a gray background with padding inside.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow -- MDN > w3schools

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CGqa5/1/

CSS

```
.outer{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: #999999;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 10px;
}
.inner{ 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #ffffff;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But why not using shadow?

Comment: You would want to use padding in most cases, because sometimes you have a container that has a background pattern and lots of elements placed inside it.

You would use padding to give those objects padding from the other objects.

Shadow styling should just be used to give objects esthetic shadows.

Answer (score 0):

Using box-shadow you just need to add one line to your css!

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #888888;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3vVZQ/